# Update a column in a table

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I need to update a column in a table which is of int data type but the values from other table i used for updating is nvarchar.
wheather this is achieved if so please let me know.

Comment: Are the values from nvarchar column numbers?

Comment: It may be numbers or character . If it is a number than insert it with the same but if it is a character than how can it be achieved

Answer (score 2):

It could be something like this:

```
update tablename
set t.column = convert(int, t2.column)
from tablename t
inner join secondtablename t2 on t.column = t2.column
where ISNUMERIC(t2.column) = 1
```

Comment: nitpick: set t.column should just be column.  can't use aliases in the column name for the set.

Comment: @Rob [You can use alias in the set clause](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/70522/you-can-use-alias-in-the-set-clause)

Comment: well, I'll be.  Is that something new?  I'm certain I've tried that before and gotten an error...

Comment: @Rob I don't know and I see no reason to use it. You can only update one table at a time.

Comment: exactly.  I know you get an error if you try to alias the table in the update part of the statement.  Maybe that's the error I'm thinking about?  no idea..

Comment: `convert(int, t2.column)` can be excluded as `where ISNUMERIC(t2.column) = 1` is in place.

Comment: Just remember that `ISNUMERIC()` only checks to make sure that the argument can be parsed into at least one type `NUMERIC`; this includes `int`, `decimal`, `money`, etc. `ISNUMERIC('112.50')` returns 1, but trying to `CONVERT` that value to an int or some decimal type may produce unexpected results.

Comment: @mikurski indeed, nicelly checked! I've put the `convert` again.

Answer (score 0):

If all you data in the nvarchar column are numbers, then, you should be able to do:

```
update ATable
set intColumn = cast(o.chardata as int)
from ATable a
join OtherTable o on a.tableid=o.tableid
```

now, you can also put in logic to handle non numeric data with an ISNUMERIC() constraint.

I see aF beat me to the punch.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #t
(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
    Column1 int
)

CREATE TABLE #t1
(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
    Column2 Varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO #t(Column1)VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO #t(Column1)VALUES(2)

INSERT into #t1(Column2)values('Alpha Numeric')
INSERT into #t1(Column2)values('12')

UPDATE t
SET t.Column1 = t1.Column2
FROM #t t
INNER join #t1 t1 on t.ID = t1.ID
Where ISNUMERIC(t1.Column2) = 1

select * FROM #t

DROP TABLE #t
DROP TABLE #t1
```